# ZK framework: resize event and jquery

Tags: jquery, autoresize, zk

I'm using ZK framework on my web and I have the following problem.

I have an image that changes its position when resizing the browser. I control the position with:

```
<script>
$(window).resize(function() { 

...........

image.css("top", puntoY); 
image.css("left", puntoX);

});
</script>
```

It only changes its position when I release the mouse button, not while I am moving the mouse, is there a way to have it in a smooth way? I mean, sending events althoug I have not released the mouse button?

Another problem is that when I resize the browser sharply, the event is not send so my image does not move. where can it be the problem?

I write my .zul code

```
<window sizable="true" height="100%" width="100%" sclass="window">
    <vbox hflex="1" vflex="1">

       <cell hflex="1" vflex="1">
        ...
       </cell>

       <cell hflex="1" vflex="2" valign="middle">
        ....    
       </cell>
       <cell hflex="1">
        ...
       </cell>
       <cell hflex="1" vflex="1">
        ....
        </cell>
    </vbox>
</window>
```

Thanks in advanced!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the drag event, here's a link that explain's it all with demo.
http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-drag-and-drop-tutorial.aspx